# how to avoid typing letters in html?

Tags: php, html

How can we avoid typing a letters or numbers in html tags? Do we still need to create a block of codes in PHP just to avoid it? or we can disabled it in through html just like this:

```
    <input type="text" />
```

instead of doing it can we make it like this?

```
    <input type="number" />
```

so that letters will not appear  if you press any letters.

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>this is for text</td><td><input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5"></td>
    <td>this for numbers</td><td><input type="number" size="5" maxlength="5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

any idea?
where should i put the javaScript?

Comment: Yes you can. Just like you suggested.

Comment: Yes, but you will always need to re-verify the data on the server as markup guarantees nothing.

Comment: what i mean is, when you press letters in keyboard it will not show up. in my example, the user can type any character.

Comment: @user3737597 that depends on which browser you are using. If you want it to act the same accross browsers, you need to use some javascript (and still validate it serverside)

Comment: is there any way to disable typing letters? can you give me an example?

Comment: @user3737597 see the answers by mooseman (if using jquery) or TJ if not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this validating for numbers on SUBMIT:

```
pattern="[0-9]{10}"
```

`{10}` here allows a maximum of 10 numbers

Take a look at the Regex cheat sheet for more info:

[link](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

OR here is the way via javascript which validates without SUBMIT:

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' />

  function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

**EDIT for user (Check for numbers on pressing enter):**

```
<input type="text" id="txtTextBox" />

$('#txtTextBox').keypress(function(event){
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    var text = $("input[type=text]").val();
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13' && !(regex.test(text))) {
     alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox'); 
}
});
```

**Jsfiddle:**

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/RC78z/105/)

Comment: got it! but how can i add ENTER key to that [0-9] value?

Comment: What do you mean by enter key? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: what i want is while i am typing numbers to the text field and press enter it will automatically sends the number i typed. i just want to enable the "ENTER KEY", because in this example it only allows numbers to be pressed not the "ENTER KEY"

Comment: here is your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RC78z/105/

Comment: Please give it a upvote if it is helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a key press event handler and check the key code using client side script. Returning `false` will prevent the input. following is an example in javascript

```
 element.onkeypress(function(e){
   var keycode = e.which;
         /* 48-57: 0 -9
            8:backspace */
   if((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || keycode == 8 )
      return true;
   return false;
});
```

Comment: i have this code 

    <body>

Comment: @user3737597 sorry, i didn't get you…?

Comment: sorry i press enter accidentally... where do i put your code @T J?

Comment: inside a <script> block preferably just above `</body>`. don't forget to replace `element` with actual reference to your element

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="number" />` is perfectly valid. However, it will still allow the user to type letters. Here's a solution with jQuery:

```
$("#myInput").keydown(function(e){
    if(((e.keyCode < 48) || (e.keyCode > 57))&& e.keyCode != 8){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yC7un/1/

If you're not using jQuery, use the following "vanilla" JS:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").onkeydown=function(e){
    if(((e.keyCode < 48) || (e.keyCode > 57))&& e.keyCode != 8){
        return false;
    } return true;
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yC7un/2/

Comment: sorry but i am not so familiar with jQuery can we make it in php?

Comment: PHP is server-side. PHP can **not** prevent a user from typing letters.

Comment: @user3737597 I just updated my answer with a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: I would like to add here that often, users filling in a form may want to use "tab" as well. If so, you can add keycode 9 as well: if (((e.keyCode < 48) || (e.keyCode > 57)) && e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 9)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will still allow letters as input, but will not validate when the form submits.
As colburton said, your suggestion is the most correct way.

You COULD make a javascript onkeydown-function to check the user's input and overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Use patterns.

For letters:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" />
```

for numbers

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" />
```

Only work in HTML5 and input types "text, search, url, tel, email, and password", for older browsers you should go with JS/jQuery.

Comment: You can still type anything you want there. It just doesn't validate.

Comment: I forgot it validates on submit, your best option is JS then